# version 0 is not defined for fiscal year xxxx error message

Tags: sap-erp

I have an windows mobile app and in which I use SAP software as back end. But now when I try to save a reference document from front end it shows that version 0 is not defined for fiscal year 2015 error message. Is there any way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proceed as follows:

```
    Goto "OKEV".
   -Controlling Area: XXXX (eg:1000)
   -Click on Tick mark
   -Select the line indicating version 0
   -Click the Tab: u2018Setting for Each Fiscal Yearu2015 and enter the
      values relevant for the year.
   -Then SAVE.
```